# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where I want to get the max number of votes per person for an election year.

However, I also want to sum the amount of votes that they had overall. So Mark Smith would have 70 votes and John Key would have 80 votes. I've been trying to use the following code to get the max amount per columns, but I'm getting the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'
```

```
DF.loc[DF.groupby(['name', 'election_year'],['votes'].max())]

votes     name              election_year
20        Mark Smith         2020   
30        Mark Smith         2020 
40        Mark Smith         2022  
20        John Key           2000
40        John Key           2000
40        John Key           2022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you use the wrong syntax for `groupby`

```py
out = df.groupby(['name', 'election_year'])['votes'].max().reset_index()
# or to keep the index
out = df.loc[df.groupby(['name', 'election_year'])['votes'].idxmax()].sort_index()
```

```
print(out)

   votes        name  election_year
1     30  Mark Smith           2020
2     40  Mark Smith           2022
4     40    John Key           2000
5     40    John Key           2022
```

To get the sum for maximum votes, you can do

```py
out = out.groupby(['name'], as_index=False)['votes'].sum()
```

```
print(out)

         name  votes
0    John Key     80
1  Mark Smith     70
```